# How to make api calls one by one instead of concurrent

Tags: angular, typescript

**Updated: Full solution at end of answer.**

---

With a code like this:

```js
@Injectable()
export class FileUploader {

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    upload(url: string, file: File) {
        let fileReader: FileReader = new FileReader();

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            fileReader.onloadend = (e) => {
                // you can perform an action with read data here
                let content = fileReader.result;
                console.log('starting upload');
                return this.http.post(url, content)
                    .map((res) => res.json()).toPromise();
            };

            fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        });
    }
```

and usage like

```js
this.fileuploader.upload('/backend/upload', content).then(); // do something
```

But when user selects many files (like album creation on FB), all files would upload at same time thus completelly blocking the browser.

My plan was to put array of promises in some property and another private method would trigger first one; after it is done, promise would call that method again so new upload starts until all are done.

All combos I tried failed, I coudn't even compile them. Even the above code is not mine but picked from some other question.

How to do this?

---

**Edited**: Based on answer from @toskv, this is the solution I am using now. I updated answer in case others get same problem.

Again, thanks @toskv for help.

```js
@Injectable()
export class FileUploader {

    private currentTask: Promise<any> = null;

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    upload(url: string, file: File) {
        let action = () => {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                let fileReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
                fileReader.onloadend = (e) => {
                    let content = fileReader.result;
                    return this.http.post(url, content)
                        .map((res) => res.json()).toPromise()
                        .then((json) => {
                            resolve(json);
                        });
                };

                fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
            })
        };

        return this.doNext(action)
    }

    private doNext(action: () => Promise<any>): Promise<any> {
        if (this.currentTask) {
            // if something is in progress do it after it is done
            this.currentTask = this.currentTask.then(action);
        } else {
            // if this is the only action do it now
            this.currentTask = action();
        }
        return this.currentTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess `this.http` is the Angular HTTP service and it is using Observables. If so, you can use `mergeMap` or `concatMap` to achieve the desired behavior: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmap.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would wrap a call in a function you could easily wrap them like this.

```js
function chain(calls: Array<() => Promise<any>>): Promise<any> {
   return calls.reduce((previous, current) => {
       return previous.then(current);
   }, Promise.resolve(""));
}
```

What this function does is to go trough the entire list of promises (it starts with an already resolved one created by **Promise.resolve**) and add every function in the list of promises received as the then callback for the resulting promise.

It's the equivalent of doing this:

```js
Promise
  .resolve("")
  .then(first)
  .then(second);
```

An example of how to use it would be.

```js
let first = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('first');
      resolve();
    }, 3000);
  })
}

let second = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('second');
      resolve();
    }, 100);
  })
}

chain([first, second]);
```

You can find a working example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20chain(calls%3A%20%5B()%20%3D%3E%20Promise%3Cany%3E%5D)%3A%20Promise%3Cany%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20calls.reduce((previous%2C%20current)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20previous.then(current)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%20Promise.resolve(%22%22))%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20first%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20new%20Promise((resolve%2C%20reject)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20setTimeout(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('first')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%203000)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20second%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20new%20Promise((resolve%2C%20reject)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20setTimeout(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('second')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20100)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Achain(%5Bfirst%2C%20second%5D)%3B).

You can also easily create the list of promise returning functions from an array of items like this.

```js
let files = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

function uploadFile(file) {
  return Promise.resolve<any>('v');
}
let uploads = files.map((file) => () => uploadFile(file))
chain(uploads);
```

Following our discussion in chat. What it looks like you really need is a service that can queue incoming requests. 
Here's an example in plain typescript. You should be able to just annotate it with @Inject and use it as is in your file upload service.

```js
class QueuedDispacherService {
  private currentTask: Promise<any> = null;

  constructor() { }

  doNext(action: () => Promise<any>) {
    if (this.currentTask) {
      //if something is in progress do it after it is done
      this.currentTask = this.currentTask.then(action);
    } else {
      if this is the only action do it now
      this.currentTask = action();
    }
    return this.currentTask;
  }
}


let dispatcher = new QueuedDispacherService();


let action1 = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('first task done!');
      resolve('done 1!');
    }, 10000);
  })
}


let action2 = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('second task done!');
      resolve('done 2!');
    }, 300);
  })
}

dispatcher.doNext(action1);
dispatcher.doNext(action2);
```

The action functions you can create the same as in the previous example.

And [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20QueuedDispacherService%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20private%20currentTask%3A%20Promise%3Cany%3E%20%3D%20null%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20doNext(action%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20Promise%3Cany%3E)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(this.currentTask)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this.currentTask%20%3D%20this.currentTask.then(action)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this.currentTask%20%3D%20action()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20this.currentTask%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20dispatcher%20%3D%20new%20QueuedDispacherService()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20action1%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20new%20Promise((resolve)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20setTimeout(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('first%20task%20done!')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve('done!')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%2010000)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20action2%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20new%20Promise((resolve)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20setTimeout(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('second%20task%20done!')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve('done!')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20300)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adispatcher.doNext(action1)%3B%0D%0Adispatcher.doNext(action2)%3B%0D%0A) it is working.

With this you can also listen to each upload by subscribing to the promise returned by the **doNext** method.

```js
dispatcher.doNext(action1).then((result) => console.log(result));
dispatcher.doNext(action2).then((result) => console.log(result));
```

The code can be shortened if you initialize the **currentTask** with a resolved promise.

```js
class QueuedDispacherService {
  private currentTask: Promise<any> = Promise.resolve();

  constructor() { }

  doNext(action: () => Promise<any>) {
    return this.currentTask = this.currentTask.then(action);
  }
}
```

This diagram shows what happens at runtime. In the end all the Promise API does is to help you to deal more elegantly with callbacks.

[image]

Comment: The thing is that I can't send an array but only one by one. And I am complete beginner in ts and ng but I will start with your answer and work from there.

I am marking your answer as accepted but if it is not hard for you, can you please write correct solution from my FileUploader server? I am still lost in promises and observables.

Comment: how are you calling this method? how are you receiving the files that you can't send them as an array? Make a question about that. ;)

Comment: Well this function is called from multiple components in the application. User would pick files from component A and send array of files, that is not a problem. But while this is uploading, user will do another file selection from component B.

There is another reason; I plan to do image resizing -before- the upload. That is why I need a promise one by one so I don't kill the browser when user selects 20+ files.

Comment: ok, then the solution needs to be different.. you ought to build a queuing mechanism in the folder when uploading the files. So that even when this method is called separately they wait for the previous uploads to finish.

Comment: @Zeljko check out the updated answer, it might help you. :)

Comment: OMG, this is amazing! Thank you, it works perfectly. I updated my question with full solution in case someone needs it. And I am not going to lie, I don't understand it but it is something I can learn from.

Comment: it's pretty simple. Considering that the server is always the same instance. We can use the Promise api so when someone calls us we either execute it instantly or if something is already going on (we have a promise), call it when that is done (Promise.then(action). Then we replace the current task with the new one we just created. I'll add something more visual later after I get off work.

Comment: I just realized, you can initialize the currentTask with an already resolved Promise (Promise.when()), and you no longer need the if inside the doNext method. :)

Comment: I wish I knew how. For years I have been working with callbacks (anon functions) in php so promises still don't click to me. I mean, I do get the idea but it is still not natural for me to read the code.

Comment: there are plenty of resources out there. get informed it will help you a lot. :)

Comment: @Zeljko check out the diagram, I hope it helps understand what's going on.

Comment: Perfect, I can't thank you enough. This entity solution helped me a lot in understanding promises.

Comment: I'm sure there's plenty left to understand about them.. it's not the most easy api to get along.. this might be an interesting read https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html